# How do I solve this flutter installation issue?

Tags: flutter

I am running on a Windows 10 machine and want to install the flutter to my PC. Upon following the first step to install it I've been keeping stuck by this error. I thought re doing it would just get it over, but yeah no. it keeps on getting the error again. Could I get someone to solve this ?

remote: Enumerating objects: 289848, done.
error: 5920 bytes of body are still expected0 MiB | 29.00 KiB/s
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
[pls check here this is the msg I've been getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sESeZ.png)

Comment: Try downloading the zip file instead

Answer (score 0):

Have you write rights on that location?
Does it work when you download the zip file from here https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows and extract it in that folder? (note: if the context for admin rights pops up, it means you dont have write rights in there and you should activate the powershell with admin rights in the future)

Comment: this user is trying to clone the repo, and since the repo is public, he does not need any rights to it. :)

Comment: Guess your windows and the C:/ folderstructure says something else

Answer (score 0):

First off, try instead using the Git desktop application. This will make it easier for you, as long as you don't need to do anything too complex on git, besides just cloning, pulling, pushing and merging with a master branch.

https://desktop.github.com/

Second, this is not an issue with flutter, this sounds like it might be a firewall issue. Do you by any chance have any antivirus software running that could be blocking the connection?
If that's the case for example, if you are running with AVG, just turn off the internet security option, then you should be able to clone the repo.